# Can Launchbar tag files?

Tags: macos, finder-tag, launchbar

I have [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index-de.html) auto select anything that is dropped into my downloads folder. I wanted to run a [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) rule but only on files with a certain tag and I want to do this with LaunchBar.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging is supported since LaunchBar 6, [released June 11, 2014](http://blog.obdev.at/post/launchbar-6-released/).

- You either send a file or a selection of files from Finder to LB
  (`alt` + holding `space`) or select a file (or – with [nightly build
  6.1](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/releasenotes-nightly.html) – a selection of files) within LB.
- Then press `tab`, type a part of the Finder tag name and add the tag 
  by pressing `return`. You have also the option to replace existing tags with the new tag.

You can display a file’s tags by pressing `→` after selecting the file in LB.

LaunchBar 6.3 [added support to work with multiple tags](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/releasenotes.html) at once.